# How to mock a class to be found via reflection?

Tags: unit-testing, reflection, mstest

I have a method that finds a class using reflection, and I want to unit test it.

In assembly to be tested:

```
namespace MyApp.Workers
{
    internal interface IWork { void DoWork() }

    internal class RealWork : IWork { public void DoWork() { /* impl omitted */ } }
}

namespace MyApp.Helpers
{
    internal static class ClassFetcher
    {
        public static Type GetWorkClass(string className)
        {
            string qualifiedClassName = typeof(IWork).Namespace + "." + className;
            cls = Type.GetType(qualifiedClassName);
            if (cls == null)
                throw new Exception($"Can't find class \"{className}\".");
            if (!typeof(IWork).IsAssignableFrom(cls))
                throw new Exception($"The class \"{className}\" doesn't implement IWork.");
        }
    }
}
```

In test assembly:

```
// Usings omitted...

namespace MyApp.Workers
{
    // Class that does implement IWork.
    public class TestWork : IWork { public void DoWork() {} }

    // Class that does not implement IWork.
    public class TestNoWork { }
}

namespace MyApp_Test.Helpers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTestClassFetcher
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FindsWorkClass()
        {
            ClassFetcher.GetWorkClass("TestWork");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void DoesNotAcceptNoWorkClass()
        {
            ClassFetcher.GetWorkClass("TestNoWork");
        }
    }
}
```

On the `GetWorkClass` calls from the test assembly, the `Type.GetType(...)` call inside `GetWorkClass` returns null. If I pass `"RealWork"` from the test method it works.

So, how can I enable the `Type.GetType(...)` call inside the assembly to be tested to find the test classes that are declared inside the unit test assembly?

Suggestions both with and without third-party frameworks, tools, addons are welcome.

**SOLUTION**
As per the comment from @LasseV.Karlsen and the marked answer from @dymanoid, I just changed the test method's code like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FindsWorkClass()
{
    string namespace = typeof(IWork).Namespace;
    string className = typeof(TestWork).AssemblyQualifiedName.Substring(namespace.Length + 1);
    ClassFetcher.GetWorkClass(className);
}
```

Comment: To mock a class for this method, either replace the whole method during test, or if you need to actually test this method, generate a real class (for test purposes) and specify its qualified name when calling the GetClass method. You cannot dynamically mock a class at runtime for this method because reflection will return existing classes.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes, I do need to "actually test this method". Your suggestions is what I've tried, but `GetType()` returns null if I pass the name of a class that's declared in the unit test assembly.

Comment: You need to provide a more qualified name then, unless you're using `Assembly.GetType`, in which case it won't work. You can specify a name that includes which assembly the type resides in, and this assembly will even be attempted loaded if it isn't already. And now I refreshed the question and see that you've both provided the actual code of the method, as well as gotten an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), because your test type resides in a different assembly, not where the `GetWorkClass` method is defined. Without providing the full assembly qualified name, the `Type.GetType` method searches only in the executing assembly and in `mscorlib`.

Either change your method's implementation such that it uses assembly qualified names (e.g. by providing the assembly name as an optional parameter), or define the `TestWork` class in the same assembly where the `GetWorkClass` is defined (that's not a good suggestion, however).

Comment: Great! I didn't know that. It works. And since the string that constitutes the assembly qualification is placed after the namespace qualified class name, I don't have to change the code inte `GetWorkClass`. I just append the extra string.